# MySQLi associative array of results in PHP 5.2.6

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there a way to fetch an associative array of results in MySQLi using PHP 5.2.6?

I know is PHP 5.3+ you can use `get_result()`. I know there is `bind_result()` in PHP 5.2.6 although there can be any number of columns in the query (not a set number.)

Been pulling my hair out over this one, ANY help will be appreciated!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php ? that's marked as simply "PHP 5", which means 5.0+

Comment: Or `fetch_array` with `MYSQLI_ASSOC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedural :

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc ( mysqli_result $result )
```

Object Oriented :

```
mysqli_result::fetch_assoc ( void )
```

More info : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.It Fetches a result row as an associative array.

From the [doumentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)..

`Returns an associative array of strings representing the fetched row in the result set, where each key in the array represents the name of one of the result set's columns or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset`